# assigning a factor to a data frame

Tags: r

I want to add a column to a data frame which will encode the specific levels of a factor. e.g.

```
subject  rate
1          12
1          10 
1          13
4          4
4          6
4          12
2          9
2          2
2          5
6          17
6          10
6          1
```

in the above data frame I wish add a third column called "treatment" where subjects are assigned to one of two levels "a" or "b". e.g. below

```
subject  rate  treatment
1          12      a
1          10      a
1          13      a
4          4       b
4          6       b
4          12      b
2          9       b
2          2       b
2          5       b 
6          17      a
6          10      a
6          1       a
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are the assignments at random or follow some specific rules? If the latter, what are the rules?

Comment: Hi Gavin, sorry for the delay. The treatment assignment is not at random. I want to be able to specify which subjects are assigned to each treatment. e.g. 1+2 are treatment a and 4+2 are treatment b in the above example.

Comment: You mean 1+6 are treatment "a" and 4 + 2 treatment "b". Anyway, specify a matrix/data.frame like the `Treat` in my Answer with the mapping you want, then do the merge. You don't need to code before the merge step. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another approach using the plyr package:

```
library(plyr)

#Make some fake data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(subject = rep(c(1,4,2,6), each = 3), rate = sample(1:20, 12, TRUE))

set.seed(1)
#Assign treatment based on the subject ID. This does not ensure that you will get
#at least one subject in each treatment group.
ddply(dat, "subject", transform, treatment = sample(letters[1:2], TRUE))
```

**EDIT - to address your comment**

Given that you want to specify which subject gets assigned to which treatment, Gavin's suggestion of `merge` is spot on. I would first make a new data.frame that contains one record for each unique subject, assign their treatment, and then merge them together:

```
treatments <- data.frame(subject = unique(dat$subject), treats = c("a", "b", "b", "a"))
merge(dat, treatments)
```

Note that the order of `unique(dat$subject)` is 1,4,2,6 which corresponds to the order of the values in the original data.frame. If your real problem contains more than four subjects, you may want to consider a more automated way of assigning treatments groups. One approach I've used in the past is to assign a random number to each respondent, and then assign groups based on a given threshold of that random number. It is essentially the same as the approach above, but can ensure that you get equal numbers in each group. For example:

```
dat <- ddply(dat, "subject", transform, treatment = runif(1))
dat <- within(dat, treatment <- ifelse(treatment < quantile(treatment, 0.5),"a", "b"))
```

Comment: err package! Martin Meachler won't be pleased! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to assign treatments at random, this will do it:

```
## subject IDs
subj <- with(dat, unique(subject))

## how many treatment levels?
ntreat <- 2

## sample an identifier for the treaments
set.seed(47)
treats <- sample(letters[seq_len(ntreat)], length(subj), replace = TRUE)

## stick this into a subject/treatment data frame
Treat <- data.frame(cbind(subject = subj, treatment = treats))
```

This gives:

```
R> Treat
  subject treatment
1       1         b
2       4         a
3       2         b
4       6         b
```

**Edit:**

If the treatments have been pre-assigned, then just create the `Treat` data frame by hand;

```
Treat <- data.frame(subject = c(1,4,2,6), treatment = c("a","b","b","a"))
```

If you have lots of these to do you can use functions like `seq()` and `rep()`, plus the inbuilt `letters` constant to speed up the "data entry".

**End edit**

We can now use this data frame in a merge with the original data to insert the `treatment` for the respective `subject`, using `merge()`:

```
R> merge(dat, Treat)
   subject rate treatment
1        1   12         b
2        1   10         b
3        1   13         b
4        2    9         b
5        2    2         b
6        2    5         b
7        4    4         a
8        4    6         a
9        4   12         a
10       6   17         b
11       6   10         b
12       6    1         b
```

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you have some key how to transform this data, like for instance 1,6=>a, 4,2=>b.
Then the `ifelse` and `%in%` mix should do the job:

```
df$treatment<-factor(ifelse(df$subject%in%c('1','6'),'a','b'))
```

The more general option is to copy this factor and alter its levels, but the details are dependent on how do you have your dictionary stored. Simple example:

```
x<-df$subject; levels(x)<-c('a','b','b','a')
x->df$treatment
```

(In both examples I assume that subject is a factor)

Answer (score 0):

An another approach may be writing a special function to decide the treatment with respect to subject and apply the function on subject to create a new treatment column.

Here is the code:

```
data <- data.frame(subject = as.numeric(rep(c(1,2,4,6)), each = 4), rate = sample(1:20, 16, TRUE))

cat = function(x){
  if (x == 1 || x == 4){return('a')}
  else if (x == 2 || x == 6 ) {return('b')}
  else { NaN}
}

data$treat = lapply(data$subject, cat)

head(data)
```

### Output:

```
> head(data)
  subject rate treat
1       1   15     a
2       2   20     b
3       4    8     a
4       6   16     b
5       1   19     a
6       2    5     b
```